# Echo only folder(s) with a certain regex in batch?

Tags: regex, batch-file

I'm trying to echo to the screen all the sub-folder/directories only in the current path with a certain type of regex (that starts with "JobResults"), but nothing is showing on the screen.

```
For /d %i in ("C:\Interns 2013 Projs\JobResults*") DO echo %~ni
```

If I replace /d with /r, only files not directories are echoed to the screen

Comment: Strange - your code worked perfectly happily for me - assuming you want the directorynames under just the one directory `C:\Interns 2013 Projs` that start with `jobresults` `(@echo ...` should give you a more-readable result)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
For /d /r "C:\Interns 2013 Projs" %i in (JobResults*) DO echo %~ni
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for all subfolders whose name starts with `JobResults`, like

```
C:\Interns 2013 Projs\JobResults 23
C:\Interns 2013 Projs\bar\JobResults_42
```

something like this should work:

```
@echo off

for /r %%d in (.) do (
  echo %%~nd | findstr /r "^JobResults" >nul 2>&1 && echo %%~fd
)
```

If you're looking for all subfolders of those folders in the working directory whose name starts with `JobResults`, like

```
C:\Interns 2013 Projs\JobResults 23
C:\Interns 2013 Projs\JobResults 23\foo
C:\Interns 2013 Projs\JobResults 23\foo\bar
```

something like this should work:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /a:d /s') do (
  echo %%~d | findstr /r "^%CD:\=\\%\\JobResults" && echo %%~d
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the results only to be echoed to the screen, this will do:

```
dir /s /ad /b "C:\Interns 2013 Projs\JobResults*"
```